# Creating chess UI from scratch

Tags: java

I want to create a basic, very simple chess GUI but the problem is I have no clue how and where to start. I want basic 64 squares, put some pieces on it, and be able to drag it to another square. I can write the logic behind it, like detect if that move is possible etc. I just never really got to make any GUI. I do know some theory of how it works (`Panels`, `handlers`, `listeners`) but no practice, any hints or links where this topic is explained?

Comment: You'll probably want to start with [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: There are many tutorials on `AWT` and `Swing` available which you can refer. That's an idea of where to start. And the tutorials will teach you on how to. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out these tutorials and resources.  They include also the AI programming, but the basics start with UI:

1) [Simple Chess Engine programming Video Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-2uSg4Kvb0&list=PLQV5mozTHmaffB0rBsD6m9VN1azgo5wXl)

2) [Advanced Chess Engine programming Video Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_2-LOvr5E8&list=PLQV5mozTHmacMeRzJCW_8K3qw2miYqd0c)

3) [Chess Programming Java Resources](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Google Image search for the pieces.  Just make sure you find ones that are licensed for redistribution and are free.  For the squares, I would programatically make the buttons.  The buttons can be image buttons.  Here is some pseudocode that might help you along.

```
Square square;
Square[][] board = new Square[8][8];


int i=0;
for(int x=0;x<8,x++)
for(int y=0;y<8,y++)
{
i++;
if (i % 2 == 0) square = new SquareFactory(this,BLACK); else SquareFactory(this,WHITE);
square.setX(x);
square.setY(y);
board[x][y] = square;




}
```

The SquareFactory should give you blank Square objects, which should have at a minimum:

```
int x,y;
public static ImageButton button;
public static final int WHITE=&ffffff;
public static final int BLACK=0;
private Piece piece;
private static int colour;
```

Then add getters and setters for the piece, such that if the piece changes, you update your view.